# error while trying to cast javax.mail.multipart

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Hi i m writing a program to scan emails for attachments and save those attachments locally, but i keep getting the following error (code follows after the error msg) thanks

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart
    at reader.main(reader.java:70)
                    Multipart multipart =  (Multipart) message[i].getContent();
                    for (int j = 0, m = multipart.getCount(); j < m; i++){
                        Part part = multipart.getBodyPart(j);

                        String disposition = part.getDisposition();

                        if ((disposition != null)&& (disposition.equals(Part.ATTACHMENT)|| (disposition.equals(Part.INLINE)))){
                            saveFile(part.getFileName().toString(), part.getInputStream());

                        }
                    }


    }

    // Close connection 
    folder.close(false);
    store.close();


}
    static void saveFile(String filename, InputStream in){
        File file = new File("c:/temp/" + filename);
        for (int i = 0; file.exists ();i++) {
           file = new File(filename + i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is from the cast to Multipart in the following line:

```
Multipart multipart =  (Multipart) message[i].getContent();
```

Check that the result from getContent is a valid cast to Multipart.

Comment: is there another way of getting the attachments from an email?